# React-Native Using Expo. - How to make the application always run in Landscape mode

Tags: react-native, screen-orientation, expo-screen-orientation

I'm using expo to develop my first react-native app. - I want the app to run in Landscape mode all the time, regardless of how the user is holding the device.

How can I achive this?

I have tried to use 'expo-screen-orientation'.

After installing it

In my app.js file I have this import startment:

```js
import { ScreenOrientation } from 'expo-screen-orientation';
```

Then call ScreenOrientation.lockAsync in a useEffect hook:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  (async () => {
    await ScreenOrientation.lockAsync(ScreenOrientation.OrientationLock.LANDSCAPE_LEFT);
   }
  )();
}, []);
```

That doesn't seem to work.

In my console I get this warning messaege:

```
> Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 1): TypeError: undefined is
> not an object (evaluating
> '_expoScreenOrientation.ScreenOrientation.lockAsync')
```

Comment: Have you been through this: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/screen-orientation/#configuration-in-appjsonappconfigjs

Comment: yes @devpolo - I have